# Subversion merge changes by character, not by line

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

Is there anything that would allow to merge changes by character/word, rather than by whole line?

**Example**
Trunk contains:  `test(a1,a2,a3)`
Branch contains:`test(a1,a2)`

The `a3` is part of a new feature, that isn't meant for trunk yet.
However, a bugfix is done one trunk, which changes `a1` -> `a0`

SVN Merge fails due to conflict on this line.

If this a limitation of Subversion that it work on "by line" basis only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, SVN will always show a conflict in this case.

But a conflict does not mean the merge "failed". It just means it can't finish automatically and you need to help it complete the merge.

Get a good 3-way merge tool like Meld or KDiff3 and this sort of conflict is very easy to resolve.

Comment: So, if I tell TortoiseSVN to use a different merge tool, will it **automatically** resolve more conflicts?

Comment: No, the tool is only presented to the user when SVN cannot resolve the merge on its own.  It does not change how SVN attempts to resolve a merge conflict.

Comment: But sometimes the tool itself can automatically do the merge for you so that all you need to do is check its work. Normally it just makes it easier to see what needs to be done, however.